# UWP, C++/Cx FileOpenPicker

Tags: uwp, c++-cx, filepicker

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with this.

```
    // STORAGE FILE
    StorageFile^ saveFile;

    // FILE PICKER, FOR SELECTING A SAVE FILE
    FileOpenPicker^ filePicker = ref new FileOpenPicker;

    // ARRAY OF FILE TYPES
    Array<String^>^ fileTypes = ref new Array<String^>(1);
    fileTypes->Data[0] = ".txt";

    filePicker->ViewMode = PickerViewMode::Thumbnail;
    filePicker->SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId::Desktop;
    filePicker->FileTypeFilter->ReplaceAll(fileTypes);

    // THIS SHOULD HOPEFULLY LET US PICK A FILE

    saveFile = filePicker->PickSingleFileAsync();
```

specifically the last line:

```
saveFile = filePicker->PickSingleFileAsync();
```

I get the following error.

> error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation ^' to 'Windows::Storage::StorageFile ^'

Comment: You have to await any async operation.  Use create_task() or the co_await extension keyword.  Lots of example code out there.

Comment: You can also just append the file type to the existing vector -- you don't have to replace the contents with your own array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation ^' to 'Windows::Storage::StorageFile ^'

`PickSingleFileAsync` is asynchronous method, and the return type is `Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation`,it can't be convert to `StorageFile` type. As Hans Passant said you could use `create_task()` to await this async operation.

```
create_task(folderPicker->PickSingleFolderAsync()).then([this](StorageFolder^ folder)
{
    if (folder)
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
    else
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
});
```

For more please refer to [**Asynchronous programming in C++**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-in-cpp-universal-windows-platform-apps).